# Apigee errorcode: steps.servicecallout.ExecutionFailed - Reason: ResponseCode 400 is treated as error

Tags: apigee

**The Problem**

The Apigee proxy is transforming the true API response of (Status Code 400 with empty JSON) to Status Code 500 and a canned Apigee error response.

**API Response Without Apigee**

`Status Code 400: Bad Request`
`{}`

***API Response Through Apigee***

`Status Code 500: Internal Server Error`

```
{
    "fault": {
        "faultstring": "Execution of ServiceCallout serverPermitGetCallout failed. Reason: ResponseCode 400 is treated as error",
        "detail": {
            "errorcode": "steps.servicecallout.ExecutionFailed"
        }
    }
}
```

**The Question**

[Apigee Docs](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/troubleshoot/policies/runtime/service-callout-runtime-errors) doesn't seem to help.

I want Apigee to skip interception and message injection (transformation), and let the original result and status code pass through.

I've tried a combination of RaiseFault scenarios, but got nowhere. I get the feeling those are intended for Request.

What am I missing here? Surely this is a simple thing, but I cannot seem to figure out what I need to setup.

***Proxy Endpoint***

```
        <Flow name="getServerPermit">
            <Condition>(proxy.pathsuffix MatchesPath "/abc**") and (request.verb = "GET")</Condition>
            <Description/>
            <Request>
                <Step>
                    <Name>serverPermitGetCallout</Name>
                </Step>

            </Request>
            <Response>
                <Step>
                    <Name>serverPermitAssign</Name>
                </Step>
            </Response>
        </Flow>
```

***Policy Callout***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ServiceCallout async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="abcServerPermitGetCallout">
    <DisplayName>serverPermitGetCallout</DisplayName>
    <Properties/>
    <Request clearPayload="true" variable="serverPermitGetCalloutRequest">
        <Set>
            <Verb>GET</Verb>
        </Set>
        <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>false</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
    </Request>
    <Response>serverPermitGetCalloutResponse</Response>
    <HTTPTargetConnection>
        <Properties/>
        <URL>https://{abc_endpoint}/api/consume/auth?{request.querystring}</URL>
    </HTTPTargetConnection>
</ServiceCallout>
```

***Policy Assign***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AssignMessage async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="abcServerPermitAssign">
    <DisplayName>serverPermitAssign</DisplayName>
    <Properties/>
    <AssignTo createNew="true" transport="http" type="response"/>
    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
    <Set>
        <Payload contentType="application/json" variablePrefix="%" variableSuffix="#">
            %serverPermitGetCalloutResponse.content#
        </Payload>
    </Set>
</AssignMessage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, any non 2xx response from a service callout policy is treated as an error as you see from the response. There are two ways to override this behavior.

1. Set the `continueOnError` flag in your service callout policy to true. This would ignore all errors arising out of the policy and continues with the flow.
2. Use the `Properties` tag under `HTTPTargetConnection` in your service callout policy to set the `success.codes` property to treat 400 status code as success response.

**References:**

- https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/policies/service-callout-policy#servicecalloutattributes
- https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/endpoint-properties-reference#targetendpointtransportpropertyspecification

Comment: This felt like a hard problem to describe. I had been trying to use Raise Fault, but it wasn't until I set the previous steps (the callout step) `continueOnError` to true that the Raise Fault was triggered. 

To access the response data from within the Raise Fault, I had to use the callout `<Response>variableName</Response>`.

Your answer is good and worked for me.  Thanks.